# Can you create classes without the type function?

Tags: python, metaclass

*This is a question for deeper understanding, I understand that in practice, use cases for something like this would be extremely rare (though by all means I'm eager to hear of them).*

If I understand correctly, the default metaclass used to generate all classes is the `type(..., ..., ...)` constructor function. In all examples I've seen of using *custom metaclasses*, at some point you are still calling the `type(..., ..., ...)` constructor function as well. You might be returning a pre-existing value, but still you at some point called `type` or one of the built-in classes to produce what you return.

Is this always the case? Is there a way to use this feature where you don't use `type` at some point? Are there alternate methods to producing classes? Python seems to almost-always have some sort of well-actually-there's-a-protocol trick under the sheets.

Comment: The `class ...: ...` syntax is basically syntactic sugar around `type(...)`. 99% of the time you'll use `class` and `metaclass=...` syntax to create classes and classes from metaclasses. For the 1% of the time where you need to create classes and/or metaclasses dynamically, you'd use `type`. Does that clear things up…?

Comment: I understand that @deceze I'm more wondering if there's a deeper api available under `type(...)` (as there often seems to be in python) or just alternate ways of achieving similar things (short of `compile()`)

Comment: I think `type` is the most fundamental object in python and cannot be replaced: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/29ea68bd1dcf30842c2ed908a6d815bc1d90f484/Doc/c-api/typeobj.rst

Comment: How much "deeper" do you want to get? C? Bytecode? `type` is already just taking parts and putting them together into a useable thing…

Comment: I mean, `iter` seems pretty fundamental too but just wraps a couple of protocols so I'm not sure its such a wild question. Granted, you're not really passing anything to `type` that could have a protocol on it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without calling the type "function" (it is actually a class), yes.
Without calling, at some step the  `type.__new__` method, no.
Not in pure Python code - it would be possible with a native code extension, that would re-use the data structures of Python itself. I'd not recommend trying it, but for playing around.

The formal way for doing it without calling `type` is to use `types.new_class`. It will,however, call `type.__new__` internally.

BTW, for creating any instance of any class, with Python code, it is just the same with one of the built-in types `.__new__`. Usually `object.__new__`  is needed, unless you subclass one of the other built-ins (int, float, list, dict) - some of those will bypass `object.__new__` and instantiate the your subclass directly - but they can only do that using native code and manipulating the structures that represent an object directly.

ok, both things *should* be possible with ctypes, which allow you to manipulate the memory structures in "raw" and call the internal APIs. And therefore in "pure Python" - but the idea is the same: you have to redo the workings of `object.__new__`  or `typing.__new__` and *correctly* populate the data structures that represent these objects. That would be way more cumbersome than doing the same from a C file.